# Is any work done when we force is being applied on any point but only the point of application moves but body does not

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, energy, work, power

In most of the cases when we apply force to any rigid body on any point the body itself starts moving but what about the elastic sort of body ,if I apply any force and only that particular point moves insteady of body itself ,will I consider it as work done or not??I am confused

Answer (score 1):

You will have done work. Mathematically, $W = F \cdot dS$. Since that "particular point" moved, there is a nonzero displacement in the direction of the force, and work is done.

Comment: I am currently solving a book,which has the same question but the answer behind says that no work is done by a force if the object is stationary but the point of application of force moves ON THE OBJECT...what conclusion should I draw

Comment: Did the object actually move? Your question makes it sound like it is deforming (i.e., changing shape). That's the case I answered, and the answer is yes.  Or are you saying that the point of application of the force moves, but the object neither deforms or moves? In that case the answer is no.

Comment: The question didn't specify whether it is a rigid or elastic body ,so I thought that the author must be considering all the cases,Now I feel that the question is not accurate

Comment: In most cases, if the nature of body (rigid or elastic) isn't mentioned - its assumed to be a rigid body by default. Hence, if the displacement is zero - no work is done.